# Error ORA-12638 in Oracle Database 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, windows-7-x64

I am a big beginner using Oracle Database 11g Express and tried it for the first time today. I only got theorical knowledge on databases (learned SQL but never used it). So, I installed Oracle 11g today (gave them the password for system when needed). I then proceeded to launch 'Start Database' followed by the SQL command line. I entered `connect SYSTEM/password` but received :

```
ERROR: 
ORA-12638 : Credential retrieval failed
```

Following advices of various forums, I changed my sqlnet.ora file, replacing `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)` by `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)`

Didn't change anything else. But now I get the following errors :

`ERROR: 
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0`

I did **nothing else** besides installing this software and launching Start Database.

Can't really find an in-depth tutorial for it by the way.

EDIT : I followed @vercelli 's comment and [this topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95053/oracle-11g-xe-64bits-installation-problem-on-windows-7/95055). Seems like you can't install Oracle 11g XE with an user account connected to the entreprise domain (installation process can't connect to the database). So, I followed [these advices](https://community.oracle.com/message/10982625#10982625) : 
I uninstalled Oracle XE, logged as a local user, installed Oracle XE there and it worked :

[image: connected] .

But when I logged back as an user domain, I had the same issues as before : ERROR: `ORA-12638`

EDIT : Works as a domain user after changing the sqlnet.ora file as attempted before. (see my answer) Might not be optimal.

Comment: Have you set ORACLE_SID variable? OS?

Comment: @vercelli I haven't done anything else than described. I was just following tutoriels on how to install and start using Oracle express 11 and there wasn't any other step.

Comment: what OS are you using? Can you check if ORACLE_SID enviromental variable is set? Can you check if oracle process is running?

Comment: @vercelli I am on windows 7, it isn't my personnal computer. ORACLE_SID is **not** set and it seems that no oracle process is running.

Comment: Ok, check your services (services.msc) a look for OracleServiceORCL (or similar). Start it if it's down. You should check OracleOraHome_TNSListener

Comment: @vercelli I got OracleServiceXE that is started (nothing with "ORCL" in it tho). Can't find OracleOraHome_TNSListener, I got OracleXETNSListener.

Comment: Try the login method as described here: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_XE

Comment: @vercelli I get an error `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`. It then asks my username to retry and the password but entering SYSTEM and the password get me the same errors as before : `ERROR: 
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0`

Comment: set SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS) again and try on cmd: 
`set ORACLE_SID=XE
sqlplus "/ as sysdba"`

Comment: @vercelli I now get the same error as trying to connect on the SQL command line :
`ERROR: 
ORA-12638 : Credential retrieval failed`
Thank you so much btw.

Comment: go to lusrmgr.msc and check if your OS USER is a part of ora_dba group. If not, include it

Comment: @vercelli I actually am.

Comment: Check this post, it kind of looks like your problem: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95053/oracle-11g-xe-64bits-installation-problem-on-windows-7/95055

Comment: @vercelli Reading OP's answer to his own question, it seems like I got the same problem _The problem was that I tried to install Oracle 11g XE with my user account connected on the enterprise domain_ 
I will try creating a local account on this computer. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Fitx - great, you are welcome

Comment: @vercelli Updated the post about the current state of the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed @vercelli 's comment and [this topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95053/oracle-11g-xe-64bits-installation-problem-on-windows-7/95055). Seems like you can't install Oracle 11g XE with an user account connected to the entreprise domain (installation process can't connect to the database). So, I followed [these advices](https://community.oracle.com/message/10982625#10982625) : 
I uninstalled Oracle XE, logged as a local user with administrator privileges , installed Oracle XE there and it worked **on the local user**:

[image: connected] .

But when I logged back as an user domain, I had the same issues as before : `ERROR: ORA-12638`

So, I changed my sqlnet.ora file on the domain user as I had tried before (after advices from different forums who had this ORA error) :

`SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)`

to

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
```

And now It seems to work as a domain user too : I was able to connect.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)