# ORA-12638 when working under domain user

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, windows-7-x64

I have trouble connecting to my local Oracle 11g XE database. When I attempt to connect, it throws `ORA-12638 Credential retrieval failed` error.

I run it on Windows machine, under a domain user account. As suggested in [Error ORA-12638 in Oracle Database 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463516/error-ora-12638-in-oracle-database-11g), I logged in the system as a local administrator and reinstalled Oracle. After that I managed to connect.

When I logged back to my domain user account, I couldn't connect even after changing `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)` to `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)` in my sqlnet.ora file. I tried rebooting several times, but it gave me the same error.

Is there anything else I can do to fix it?

Comment: Did you change the `Log on as` user for the Oracle service and listener service to the domain user? From Windows Services?

Comment: @JSapkota no. How should I change it?